# PHP foreach loop outside loop

Tags: php, foreach, scope

I'm trying to wrap my head around PHP and variable scope. Take a look at the following:

```
<?php  foreach ($data as $tip) { ?>              
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $tip['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tip['title']; ?></td>                  
    <td class="delete"><a href="#deleteModal" class="modal"><i class="icon-cross"></a></i></td> 
  </tr>                                                
<?php } ?>
```

This just runs a foreach loop that pulls some information out of the database and displays it in a table. The last table cell has an icon in it for deleting that article. What I'm trying to do is have a modal popup that asks for conformation to delete that specific article but I cannot tie the tip id with the delete button because the modal window sits outside the loop. How can I go about accessing the individual id?

Comment: php has nothing to do with modal  popups, or popups of any sort. that's a purely client-side thing. You need some javascript to handle the click events, and those events will "know" which element was clicked on, so you can extract IDs and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
<?php  foreach ($data as $tip) { ?>              
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $tip['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tip['title']; ?></td>                  
    <td class="delete" onclick="deleteArticle(<?php echo $tip['id'] ?>)">
         <a href="#deleteModal" class="modal">
           <i class="icon-cross"></i>
         </a>
    </td> 
  </tr>                                                
<?php } ?>

<script>
   function deleteArticle(id){
     // now you can do what ever you want to do with this id
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I understand better now, thank you. Although I found out "delete" was a reserved word, so I changed the function name to "deleteArticle"

Answer (score 0):

There is a built it javascript function called "confirm".

If you're using JQuery (And I assume you are) try this:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
  var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this article?");
  if(check)
  {
    // you code here
  }
  else return false;
});
```